Blender not booting after addon installation attempt
I tried installing this addon through its python script in Blender's text editor: https://github.com/ChicoEevee/Pokemon-Switch-V2-Model-Importer-Blender?tab=readme-ov-file#readme
There wasn't any apparent effect, so I ran it multiple times (which, in hindsight, wasn't a good idea). I then went to check the addon manager to see if it was there, but it wasn't. I then clicked the install button to see if I could install it from the script itself, but Blender crashed immediately.
Now, whenever I open Blender (I use the Steam launcher), it opens for a split second before immediately closing. I have verified the file integrity and reinstalled Blender with no success.
Can anybody help me figure out the cause of the crashing? And, if possible, also tell me how exactly I can install this addon? I am unfamiliar with Python and scripting in Blender, so any help would be very appreciated.

Have you executed the script in the Script Editor ("text editor") or installed it via the menu Edit > User Preferences... > Add-ons?

When you install a script via User Preferences > Add-ons it's copied into your user home where the other preferences are stored. Since they are located in a separate folder, the installed add-ons will not be deleted when you reinstall Blender. Open the preference folder, look for the add-on folder (e.g. \Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons), and remove it.
